# PDO making a while loop function

Tags: php, loops, object, while-loop

Yeah I'm unsure how to even ask this question.

Let me just try to make an example of what I want to do here.

```
function getRecents()
{
    global $sql;
    $buffer = $sql->prepare("SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `exposure` = 'public' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5");
    $buffer->execute();
    return $buffer->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

while($pd = getRecents())
{
 echo $pd->id;
}
```

Just as if I was going to do this below. Obviously because I use recents more than once I'm not going to throw this all over the place.

```
    $buffer = $sql->prepare("SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `exposure` = 'public' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5");
    $buffer->execute();
    while($foo = $buffer->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    echo $foo->id;
```

I think someone will understand what I'm trying to do, if so please I'm so confused.
I would google it but not even sure how to.

Comment: Have you tried the following --> http://php.net/manual/ro/pdostatement.fetchall.php#example-1028 ?

Comment: Try one of MVC frameworks, CakePHP, Zend Framework, Yii or like

Comment: This sounds like a job for a `foreach` instead of a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should try something like this:

```
function getRecents()
{
    global $sql;
    $buffer = $sql->prepare('SELECT * FROM foo WHERE exposure = "public" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5');
    $buffer->execute();
    return $buffer->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

$recents = getRecents();

foreach ($recents as $item) {
    echo $item->id;
}
```

Comment: What in the world was I thinking, thank you; I'm unsure how I left out my best friend foreach.

Comment: If there will be many results in `$recents` remember to unset it after you're done.

Comment: Wont be defining it as a variable, actually passing a single param in getRecents which is for LIMIT. Man if you would of seen the way I was going about this before I'd go straight to hell in a hand basket.

Answer (score 0):

A foreach loop would be better if there is a set array of objects/arrays.

```
$buffer = $sql->prepare('SELECT * FROM foo WHERE exposure = "public" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5');
$buffer->execute();
foreach($buffer->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```